Camunda 7, Spring Boot, Eureka issue
We have created a microservice with Spring boot & embedded Camunda 7 which we are trying to register on Eureka server, but we are getting below error.
UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name ‘scopedTarget.eurekaClient’
We are using the below versions Spring-Boot: v3.2.5, Spring cloud: 2023.0.2, Camunda Platform: v7.21.0, Camunda Platform Spring Boot Starter: v7.21.0, Java 17

I resolved this issue by doing the following steps
add this dependency
<dependency>
   <groupdId>com.netflix.eureka</groupdId>
   <artifactId>eureka-client-jersey3</artifactId>
</dependency>

and create a bean
@Configuration
public class Jersey3TransportClientFactoriesConfig{
  @Bean
  public Jersey3TransportClientFactories jersey3TransportClientFactories(){
    return new Jersey3TransportClientFactories();
  }
}

in your application.yml
eureka:
  client:
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://localhost:8761/eureka
    register-with-eureka: true
    fetch-registry: false

Please let me know if any issues.
